# Is there a left adjoint to the inclusion of discrete (op)fibrations over $X$ into $\mathbf{Cat}/X$?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

This would be intended to be like the adjoint to the inclusion of $Sub(X)$, the subsets of a set $X$ into $ \mathbf{Set}/X $, namely taking the image of a function--except "one level higher".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, apparently.
http://ncatlab.org/michaelshulman/show/comprehensive+factorization